# Django, tried to add a field to exsting model raises error

Tags: python, django

I Have a Django rest framework API which contained the following model:

```py
class Points(models.Model):

    mission_name = models.CharField(name='MissionName',
                                    unique=True,
                                    max_length=255,
                                    blank=False,
                                    help_text="Enter the mission's name"
                                    )

    latitude = models.FloatField(name="GDT1Latitude",
                                 unique=False, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                 help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                 default=DEFAULT_VALUE)
    longitude = models.FloatField(name="GDT1Longitude",
                                  unique=False, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                  help_text="Enter the location's Longitude, second when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                  default=DEFAULT_VALUE)
```

Added User Field:

```py
class Points(models.Model):

     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     # rest of fields...
```

Iv'e added a User field, When trying to makemigrations and migrate it I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column find_second_gdt_points.user does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "find_second_gdt_points"."id", "find_second_gdt_point...
```

Which I don't get, of course, this column does not exist.

This is what migartions are for, no?

Comment: This might not have anything to do with your model above, do you get the same error when you run `./manage.py check`?

Comment: The django docs state that changing the user model in development is not recommended at all: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project

Comment: You can delete your migrations file and try the same command again.

Comment: @LiorPollak, So how could I link users to their objects, I want to show which user posted the object

Comment: @AbhishekKulkarni I'm new to Django, but I doubt it that it's the best course of action.

Comment: Show the actual migration file and the updated models.py

Comment: If you already had a user model in your app (most probably if you create the app using django-admin), then you should only have to add the user property to your model and do migrations. If that doesn't work, please add your complete code regarding the model and the migration.

Comment: Please post the code of all models the way they are now and also the migration file. You can of course use a ForeignKey to link to the Django-default User model - no problem here. @Lior Pollak is right - you should not change the user modal - which you are not doing when linking it to your model with FK. That is just routine.

Comment: Don't delete any migrations if your project is already in "production". Please see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding default=None,

```
class Points(models.Model):

      user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default= None)
      # rest of fields...
```

Answer (score 0):

These errors are usually because you need to include a default null value for the new field, as well as allowing it to be `nullable`, it should be as simple as:

```
class Points(models.Model):

     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
     ...
```

The reason being, is that the migration is applied to exisiting records in your database, as well as all future records. The migration needs to know how to populate the new field (column) in the DB for existing records...